# No account of type com.salesforce.androisdk found

Tags: android, salesforce

I tried to implement oauth implementation for salesforce in android.I have written the code while running I am getting binding error "No account of type com.salesforce.androisdk found".
I am attaching the Logcat along with this.If anyone has any idea regarding this can share.

```
02-19 12:33:21.149: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.172: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.192: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.212: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.233: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.252: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.270: V/TemplateApp(19970):  onCreate of Main Activity
02-19 12:33:21.291: D/AbsListView(19970): checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
02-19 12:33:21.291: V/TemplateApp(19970):  ******* default onResume of Main Activity
02-19 12:33:21.293: I/ClientManager:getRestClient(19970): No account of type com.salesforce.androisdk found
02-19 12:33:21.297: V/TemplateApp(19970):  ******* default onResume - View.INVISIBLE
02-19 12:33:21.298: V/TemplateApp(19970):  ******* default onResume - accountType ::com.salesforce.androisdk
02-19 12:33:21.298: V/TemplateApp(19970):  ******* default onResume - loginOptions ::com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.ClientManager$LoginOptions@419776e8
02-19 12:33:21.299: I/ClientManager:getRestClient(19970): No account of type com.salesforce.androisdk found
02-19 12:33:21.302: D/ActivityThread(19970): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41c67230 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41c4ade0 {com.example.contactspoc/com.example.contactspoc.MainActivity}}
02-19 12:33:21.305: D/ActivityThread(19970): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{41c67230 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41c4ade0 {com.example.contactspoc/com.example.contactspoc.MainActivity}}
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1612)
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:140)
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1458)
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
02-19 12:33:21.305: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-19 12:33:21.362: E/Posix(19970): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1612)
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:140)
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1458)
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
02-19 12:33:21.395: W/AccMgrCallback:run(19970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-19 12:33:21.466: D/OpenGLRenderer(19970): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-19 12:33:21.503: D/ActivityThread(19970): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41c67230 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41c4ade0 {com.example.contactspoc/com.example.contactspoc.MainActivity}}
02-19 12:33:21.508: D/jdwp(19970): processIncoming
02-19 12:33:21.508: D/jdwp(19970): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000106, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
02-19 12:33:21.508: I/AndroidRuntime(19970): VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given strikingly little to work with. No code? Minimal explanation? However, I am going to field the guess that you have misspelled "com.salesforce.androidsdk" and accidentally written "com.salesforce.androisdk" somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have written for salesforce authentication.But I binding error on fetching account type the "com.salesforce.androisdk" is fetched by the sdk only.I am sharing the code what I have written..

Comment: String accountType = SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getAccountType(); this method is fetching "com.salesforce.androisdk"